# Installing and using ArcGIS REST API Connector plug-in?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, arcgis-rest-api

I downloaded this plug-in  http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/connector/ from the plugins link at QGIS.org and it unzipped into a folder entitled "connector" in my "downloads" folder (running Mac Yosemite 10.10.5) but as with everything to do with QGIS, it comes with no read-me instructions. I have no idea what to do with the files that were downloaded.

Is there some folder I am supposed to put them in? or do I go to the QGIS app and point it at the plug-in somehow?

Meanwhile I tried signing up for a public account at ArcGIS and that is a hopeless affair. Is that necessary to use this plugin or does the plugin have a path to public maps there without a sign-in?

ArcGIS allowed me to enter information, it knows my username so I can't register it again but it won't allow me to sign in. It never sent an acknowledgement to my email but when I click forgot password (which I haven't, but what else can I do) it sends me a note that my account has been blocked so it has the right email.

Is there something about GIS in virtually every aspect that makes it the most intransparent uninelligble unintuitive platform to get running or am I just denser than the average user?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Plugins, Manage and Install Plugins, Settings. Enable experimental plugins.

Go to all, search for ArcGIS and install the plugin.

An ArcMap icon will appear on the Manage Layers Toolbar.

Comment: thanks, got that far, didn't realize very left column of glyphics was the manage layers toolbar, but figured it out by toggling it on and off in View/Toolbars submenu. The help folders for all programs, not just QGIS, are dastardly for not identifying various toolbars and palettes and where to find them. they always assume the user knows where to look.

so now the arcGIS icon is there and when i click it, it asks for a layer URL. not a clue where i would get that . . . maybe this is a URL at arcGIS? Still don't know if an account is needed or how i would specify lat. lon. and size of basemap.

Comment: When you only need a basemap try the OpenLayers plugin and use one of those. 

The ArcGIS REST API plugin is build to connect to REST services from a ArGIS for server. Try the samples under help if you want to try.

Comment: my concern with the openlayers approach is that it won't print high res according to what i'm reading and there can be some distortion between layers.  i can't find these samples you were suggesting, i assume you meant under the Help menu in QGIS? do i search for "basemap" in topics or how do i find them.  thanks

Comment: In the ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin window is a 'help' link in the lower left corner. This redirects to this excellent wiki page: http://giswiki.hsr.ch/ArcGIS_REST_API_Connector_QGIS_Plugin#Help

Comment: your last comment vanished. IIRC, it had an arcGIS url for topo maps as sample. I don't seem to be able to do anything with QGIS, nevermind get arcGIS maps.tried tutorial from the beginning, but it says "this assumes you have a good knowledge of QGIS". if i did i wouldn't be using the tutorial! i downloaded open street map data just as a test. that at least made sense, it asked for NSEW bounds of lat./lon. but i open resulting .osm and see nothing. if i could download  satelite and topo imagery and 'print' decent res to PDF i could do the rest in graphics and CAD programs i'm familiar with.

Comment: I'm trying to climb this steep learning curve as the only alternative i have found is taking high res screen shots of snippets of google maps and then pasting these thumbnails together into a map in a graphics program. that is incredibly frustrating and time consuming managing a thousand tiles into a map, but i'm beginning to think it would be less frustrating and time consuming than trying to ramp up on QGIS.  i learned graphics and CAD with no tutorial but i don't seem to be able to get out of the starting gate here. maybe there is a QGIS for dummies somewhere . . . ?

Comment: Just install the OpenLayers Plugin as mentioned earlier. This will let you add all kind of basemaps. It is possible to add the ArcGIS Online basemaps if you really want but as I am not a ESRI fanboy I want you to try the alternatives first.

Comment: The ESRI basemaps are to be found onder http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services. Hit one of the links under services. Hit WMTS in the top left corner. Copy the url. Go to QGIS, add WMTS connection. Enter name, paste URL. Connect, add layer.

Comment: my concern with open map continues to be the quality of output to  a .pdf but at this juncture i'll try anything that works since nothing seems to. but openlayers says i have to set the extent of a project first. i looked to define the extent under  Project>Project Properties menu but don't see it. tried starting a project with vector layer from open street map where extent is easily defined but could never see the map after 'adding it'. the cursor coordinates did not go to its center but stayed half world away upon adding and although i scrolled and entered coordinates could never find it.

Comment: and on the dual track,  thanks for the arcgis link. so i drilled down to this link: http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer/export?bbox=-179.999999,-89.999999,179.999999,89.999999  these are the fields it wants filled in. Bounding Box:  
Bounding Box Spatial Reference:  
Layers:  
Layer Definitions:  
Image Size:  
Image Spatial Reference:  
Image Format:  
Background Transparent:  True   False
DPI:  
Time:  
Layer Time Options:  
Dynamic Layers:  
Geodatabase Version Name:  
Map Scale:  
Format:

Comment: No, please read. You need to grab the url under the link WMTS and add that link as a WMTS connection in QGIS. Then connect to this added connection, select the layer and add it to QGIS. Then you will see the basemap in QGIS. It is not a file but a webservice. A Web Map Tile Service to be exact.

Comment: didn't read carefully enough. thanks for detailed approach. once i get url assume then choose Layer>Add Layer >Add WMS/WMTS Layer. then i get box to enter url for tile service, user name and password which arcGIS has screwed up and of course no response from accounts so now i'll try openlayers while i wait. i can see that the ESRI hegemony is no boon but perhaps evil necessity to open source GIS. Only considering the arcGIS approach because of my desire to print or .pdf relative high resolution versions for folks who don't GIS. (like me til a week ago)

Comment: Welcome :) You don't need username / password for the WMTS. It's open data. Just connect and add layers. Anita Graser (underdark) seems to write nice QGIS books. Check https://anitagraser.com/2016/04/15/learning-qgis-3rd-ed-discounts/